# Use wireshark to analyze raw stream without frame seperator

Tags: wireshark

My wifi sniff device can output data to a raw file. But it may begin with the middle of a frame, and each frame starts right after another. A pcap file must contain packet headers, which I don't have. So I tried to discard the half complete frame at the beginning of the file, and put the rest into a pcap file with one packet. Then wireshark can analyze the first frame, even with wrong packet size. 
My question is how to make wireshark analyze the remaining frames ?

Edit: This is a sample pcap with 2 frame, but without the second packet header

```
00000000  D4 C3 B2 A1 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Ã”ÃƒÂ²Â¡............
00000010  FF FF 00 00 69 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  Ã¿Ã¿..i...........
00000020  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 08 02 00 00 01 00 5E 00  â‚¬...â‚¬.........^.
00000030  00 FC E8 94 F6 3C 5F 40 20 68 9D 9A 4B D7 70 73  .Ã¼Ã¨â€Ã¶<_@ h.Å¡KÃ—ps
00000040  AA AA 03 00 00 00 08 00 46 00 00 20 38 F8 00 00  ÂªÂª......F.. 8Ã¸..
00000050  01 02 48 D5 C0 A8 01 66 E0 00 00 FC 94 04 00 00  ..HÃ•Ã€Â¨.fÃ ..Ã¼â€...
00000060  16 00 09 03 E0 00 00 FC 08 02 00 00 01 00 5E 7F  ....Ã ..Ã¼......^.
00000070  FF FA E8 94 F6 3C 5F 40 20 68 9D 9A 4B D7 F0 75  Ã¿ÃºÃ¨â€Ã¶<_@ h.Å¡KÃ—Ã°u
00000080  AA AA 03 00 00 00 08 00 46 00 00 20 38 F9 00 00  ÂªÂª......F.. 8Ã¹..
00000090  01 02 39 D6 C0 A8 01 66 EF FF FF FA 94 04 00 00  ..9Ã–Ã€Â¨.fÃ¯Ã¿Ã¿Ãºâ€...
000000A0  16 00 FA 04 EF FF FF FA                          ..Ãº.Ã¯Ã¿Ã¿Ãº
```

Comment: So what sort of data does your sniff device produce?  Bits, so that it's decoding the radio signals?  Or an analog waveform?

Comment: It is 802.11 frame, I use DLT_IEEE802_11 when I put data in pcap file.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to make wireshark analyze the remaining frames ?

Detect the beginnings and ends of frames in your bit sequence, and put each frame into a separate record in the pcap file.

If there's nothing in the bit sequence to allow your software to determine where one frame ends and another frame begins, there's nothing in the bit sequence to allow *Wireshark* to do so, so if you want to have Wireshark analyzer frames past the first frame, you are *FORCED* to ensure that there's something in the bit stream to determine frame boundaries, and you might as well have *your* software break the bit stream into frames.

Comment: But if wireshark could analyze the first packet, it must know where the first packet ends based on protocols it detects right ? I can write a program to generate packet headers but I don't know how to get the first packet length out of wireshark.

Comment: "But if wireshark could analyze the first packet, it must know where the first packet ends based on protocols it detects right ?"  Wrong.  It knows where the first packet ends because a pcap file record has a per-packet header with the packet length in it (time stamp, packet captured length, packet actual length), and it relies on *that* to indicate how big a packet is.

Comment: "If so then how do you explain this ?"  Easy.  Whoever wrote that file did it wrong, because there's *clearly* more than one 802.11 packet in it - there are two LLC+SNAP headers in it, as per the aa aa 03 00 00 00 08 00 appearing twice, so it *should* have been written with *two* packet headers, both with captured lengths and lengths of 64.  Wireshark's just ignoring the extra crap from the second packet, because it thinks you have 24 bytes of 802.11 header, 8 bytes of LLC+SNAP header, 24 bytes of IPv4 header, and 8 bytes of IGMPv2, and the rest (the second packet) is ignored.